# Dynamic name with SKAction

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have SKActions defined in my class, eg:

```swift
let CSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("C3.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)
let DSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("D3.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)
```

I want to be able to call a function to play sounds, and I want to adjust the name dynamically, like this:

```swift
func playSound(noteName: String) {

    print(noteName) // "C"
    var name = noteName + "Sound"
    print(name) // "CSound"
        
    run(SKAction(named: name)!)
        
}
```

This causes a fatal error on the `run(SKAction(named: name)!)` line:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Why is this? How is it nil? The variable `name` has the value `CSound`, and an SKAction does exist with that name. How can I use a dynamic name like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the sounds in a dictionary:

```
let sounds = [
    "C": SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("C3.mp3", waitForCompletion: false),
    "D": SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("D3.mp3", waitForCompletion: false),
]

let sounds = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
    ["C", "D"]
        .map { ($0, SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("\($0)3.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)) }
)
```

If there are many sounds and you don't want to repeat `playSoundFileNamed` too many times, you can do a `map`:

```
let sounds = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
    ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
        .map { ($0, SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("\($0)3.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)) }
)
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
func playSound(noteName: String) {
    if let action = sounds[noteName] {
         run(action)
    } else {
        // there is no sound with the given name...
    }
}
```

The [`SKAction(named:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417814-init) creates an `SKAction` from a .sks file in your app's bundle. You can add such a file in Xcode by doing File -> New -> File... -> SpriteKit Action. You pass in the file name as the parameter, and it creates the action encoded in the file.